# Is it possible to use autoscaler for google SQL as it is possible for compute engine

Tags: sql-server, google-app-engine, magento

Let me explain the problem. I have a magento project with 3 million products and more than 6 million urls. The problem ist only the database because of this much products. I would like to only autoscale the google cloud sql database. Then it would always respond adequate. I know its possible for google compute engine and that also includes the database. So is it possible with google or another cloud sql provider?

Comment: how exactly you want to scale your sql server? migrate to bigger server (with some downtown?)? use ephemeral slave replicas? you sure you need it to be automatic? you can do manual scale with google cloud sql

Comment: But I want to automate it like google compute engine is able to.

Comment: yes, but how exactly you image this? there are just too many ways. some of them already provided by google cloud, some not

Comment: The question is clearly "how can I auto scale sql" right?  Might be broad, but it's not "unclear"

Comment: there're no general solution for scalability of sql server. that's why we have so many NoSQL databases, each with different solution (for different aspect of the problem)

Comment: also Google Cloud SQL is scalable. so there must be something else, if it's not enough

Answer (score 3):

You cannot scale databases the same way [Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) is doing for Compute Engine managed instances. Autoscaling capabilities of Compute Engine works for stateless VMs. Databases are [stateful](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/stateless). You can use read replications to scale Cloud SQL. Read Replica instances allow data from the master instance to be replicated to one or more slaves. This setup can provide increased read throughput. Visit [this artcile](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/replication) for different read replica scenarios.

Comment: My Intention was to create read replications automatically if the database response time is too slow because of too much requests. So to activate and deactivate as many read replicas as needed.

Comment: Cloud SQL second generation offers better performance and flexibility, however it's still beta: http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/2015/12/the-next-generation-of-managed-MySQL-offerings-on-Cloud-SQL.html

Comment: The only way that I think you may be able to use Compute Engine Autoscalar for Cloud SQL read replica, is writing a script to do the steps mentioned in this article for configuring external read replica, and then creating a template and instances group of it and use GCE Autoscaling along with Network Load balancer: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/replication#replication-external